# eth_device structure handling in U-boot source

Tags: u-boot

In the `U-boot` source code, [miiphy_init()](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/4412fd8ba2ce5945d04f4b181a96e05576c46bf2/common/miiphyutil.c#L63) and [phy_init()](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/4412fd8ba2ce5945d04f4b181a96e05576c46bf2/drivers/net/phy/phy.c#L473) functions are initialising global variables for mii_dev and phy_driver structures.
I am looking for the source who will create/initialise global `structure eth_device` variable and maintain/use  it during runtime.

Basically I am trying to understand who will create `eth_device` structure and how it will be handled  during run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

struct eth_device is only used by deprecated drivers that don't follow the driver model. These should have been removed with release v2020.07.

The structure is filled in the driver initialization routine, e.g. lan91c96_initialize(). Just grep for 'eth_register(' to find all those functions.

The structure is retrieved like this:

```
struct eth_device *dev = eth_get_dev_by_name(bus->name);
```

Comment: In legacy(with out Driver Model), when we register PHY driver using phy_register then how this is linked to MAC driver? My understanding is that PHY chip can be communicated through MAC with MII/MDIO interface, so if we want to access PHY registers then MAC driver should maintain the PHY drivers to which it can communicate.

Comment: Before driver model the MAC devices are maintained by `struct eth_device *eth_devices` in `eth_legacy.c` and functions are defined in this file to navigate through `eth_devices` list. With driver model how the MAC devices are maintained? Can you guide to understand.

Comment: In the driver model the device tree defines which devices exists. If the network card uses the PCI or USB bus, it is detected via plug and play mechanisms of the bus.